# flexReload issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, flexigrid

I am using Flexigrid in my web App.When user add or delete a record,the $("#displays").flexReload function will be called,but it doesn't work in IE.
I have to relaunch IE or clear browser's cache manually. 
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem

```
**Server side solution:**  Set the HTTP headers of the response to avoid returning response from cache.

In HTML: (in the header)

<META HTTP-EQUIV=”Cache-Control” CONTENT=”no-cache”>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=”expires” CONTENT=”0″>

In PHP: (in the script)

header(”Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate”);
header(”Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT”);

In JSP: (before writing to the output stream)

response.setHeader(“Cache-Control”,”no-cache”);
response.setDateHeader (“Expires”, 0);

**Client side solution:** (1) Make HTTP POST call — only HTTP GET calls are served from cache or (2) Make sure the HTTP GET URL is different every time.

(1) Make HTTP POST call –
set method=”POST” and handle the call appropriately

(2) Append a unique parameter to the HTTP GET call so that the URL is different every time. A unique time stamp is a good choice.
The following sample code, may do the job:

var timeStampForNocache:Date = new Date() ;
params.noCacheControlVar = timeStampForNocache.getTime().toString() ;
I have named the parameter “noCacheControlVar”. You can name it anything else you please. The name does not matter. What matters is that the timestamp makes the HTTP GET URL unique.
```

Happy Coding !!!